# Unpack a dict of dicts into separate dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary called 'data' that has keys (dictionary name) and values (dictionary).

I wish to separate out the individual dictionaries from the outer dictionary.

This is how I read a folder of csv files to make the dict of dicts:

```
#read csvs with filename as dictionary names
data= dict()
for file in files:
    key = file
    val = pd.read_csv(
            csv_path + file + ".csv", index_col=0).to_dict(orient='dict')['values']
    data[key] = val
```

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: What is your desired output?  A list of dicts?

Comment: FWIW, you could save a line: `data[file] = val`

Comment: my desired output is each key to be associated with the dictionary. That is to have separate dictionaries each with the key as their name

Answer (score 0):

They could be unpacked like this:

```
master = {'dic1': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 42}, 'dic2': {'sas': 3, 'baz': 13}}

d1, d2 = master.values()
print(d1)  # -> {'foo': 1, 'bar': 42}
print(d2)  # -> {'sas': 3, 'baz': 13}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this as a loop. there are hundreds of dictionaries to unpack. i would like their name to be the key that was associated with it

Comment: Do you mean you want to create _separate variables_ whose named from the keys in the nested dictionary with the value associated with each of those keys? If not, how do you want them separated out into individual dictionaries?

Comment: yes that is what I mean. I want all those keys to be the name of the separate variables

Comment: In that case your question is a duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) — which essentially is that "no", that you don't want to do that.